# How to filter two Series of a Dataframe where the value of a list element is true in one of the series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I have a dataframe and two of the columns have list elements that have a one to one relationship.  `PhoneNumber` and `PhonePrimary`?.

```
PhoneNumber    PhonePrimary    City       Zip
__________________________________________________
[2107788451,   [True,
2107788451,     True,         San Antonio      71541
2107788451]     False]
-----------------------------------------------------
[5126508976,   [True,           
5124430261]     False]        Austin           78750
```

The other columns are just singular value elements and are independent of these columns.  I want to filter down these series elements to where the list elements in `PhoneNumber` are only the ones that match with the true values of `PhonePrimary`.  The orders match up.  Is there a way to do this without creating new columns for the outcomes, like with a filter?

Results look like:

```
PhoneNumber    PhonePrimary     City         Zip
__________________________________________________
[2107788451,    [True,
2107788451]     True]          San Antonio    71541
----------------------------------------------------
[5126508976]    [True]         Austin         78750
```

Comment: In your given sample, are the values stored in one row as an array/list, or are they 3 rows in your `DataFrame`?

Comment: What do you mean filter down? Could you put a dummy example of the original dataframe, and what the expected result is?

Comment: @r.ook  Each row for these two columns is an array of varying size.  sometimes the array is just one element like [6502352235] but they are always arrays.

Comment: @JasonChia I have edited the sample in my question.  As far as the results go, the values for each row should just be the "True" for "PhonePrimary" and those matching phone numbers for "PhoneNumber". So the array legnths will be reduced but still arrays.  So those array elements are filtered.  But the other columns are not affected, "City" and "Zip"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to iterate over the lists using `zip` and keep the `True` values.
Here's a way you can do:

```
def func(f):
    r = [ [x, y] for x,y in zip(f['PhoneNumber'] ,f['PhonePrimary']) if y]

    # separate the values (PhoneNumber & PhonePrimary values)
    col1, fl = [x[0] for x in r], [x[1] for x in r] 

    return pd.Series([col1, fl], index=['PhoneNumber','PhonePrimary'])

df1 = df.apply(func, 1)
print(df1)

                      col1          flag 
0  [2107788451, 2107788452]  [True, True]

# Finally replace the columns from existing df
df[['PhoneNumber', 'PhonePrimary']] = df1[['PhoneNumber', 'PhonePrimary']]
```

> **Sample Data**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'PhoneNumber': [[2107788451, 2107788452, 2107788453]], 
                   'PhonePrimary': [[True, True, False]],
                    'adr': ['San Antonio'],
                    'zip': 12345})
```

Comment: thanks but Im having trouble getting the results like that and understanding this method.  Why do you create a Series with all these like this?  I actually have many more columns including an index called '_id' which is a customers id.  So I need to do this '+ [f['<column name>]]' for each column?  And why is the index every single column. should id just be "_id" ?

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if you still want the lists after the operation.

`df = pd.DataFrame({'pn': [[2107788451,2107788451,2107788451], [5126508976,5124430261]], 'pp': [[True,True,False], [True,False]], 'city': ['sa', 'a'], 'zip': [71, 78]})`

`df = pd.concat([df['pn'].explode(), df['pp'].explode()], axis=1).query('pp == True').merge(df[['city', 'zip']], left_index=True, right_index=True)`

If `$` is giving you an error, do it in 2 lines

```
ndf = pd.concat([df['pn'].explode(), df['pp'].explode()], axis=1)
df = ndf[ndf['pp'].eq(True)].merge(df[['city', 'zip']], left_index=True, right_index=True)`
```

```
           pn    pp city  zip
0  2107788451  True   sa   71
0  2107788451  True   sa   71
1  5126508976  True    a   78
```

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(['pn'])

           pn    pp city  zip
0  2107788451  True   sa   71
1  5126508976  True    a   78
```

Comment: The best solution would have the single value arrays not be arrays but where there are more than one true Primary just chose the first element of the array.  so there should be only one value for each row and no duplicates.  So the index is actually a persons member_id,. Only one row per person

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'

Comment: make sure you have pandas version 0.25 to use [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax 'PhonePrimary ?==True'

Comment: oh that question mark is messing up the query, if it can't be removed you have to do it with 2 lines